# Making sense of the construct “Ich bin der Auffassung”

Tags: word-usage, phrase, grammar-identification

I understand that “Ich bin der Auffassung” means something like “I believe” or “I think”.
However, I do not understand how this makes sense **grammatically**, because when you literally translate it, it means: “I am the opinion” (I = the opinion). Is there any way to make sense of this usage, or should I just take it as it is and just memorize it?

Comment: grammatically, it is exactly like the more common *"Ich bin der Meinung"*

Answer (score 47):

## TL;DR

That's the wrong literal translation. Note that *Auffassung* is female, i.e. *die Auffassung*. Here it's in the genitive case *(der Auffassung).* More literal translations would thus be:

> I am of the opinion
>
> I am of the understanding

which make more sense.

## More detailed explanation

German nouns may change their article depending on the grammatical case. This may be confusing since they may assign an article that is used for a different gendered noun. A great start is to look up the word in a dictionary and find the corresponding articles for each case.

*Auffassung* is female, i.e.

- Nominativ: *die Auffassung*
- Genitiv:   *der Auffassung*
- Dativ:     *der Auffassung*
- Akkusativ: *die Auffassung*

It now becomes clear that it is not the nominative case in *Ich bin **der** Auffassung.*. Thus it cannot mean that you are the opinion (i.e. *Ich bin die Auffassung*). Instead genitive or dative are the only possible options. Dative does not make sense, as *Auffassung* does not receive any action/object (roughly speaking). Hence, *Auffassung* is in the genitive case and a more literal translation would be:

> I am the opinion's
>
> I am the understanding's

which seems a bit rough; so let's make them a tad more English:

> I am of the opinion
>
> I am of the understanding

which make more sense.

Comment: Great explanation, and it makes sense to me as a native speaker of English, but it makes me think that the expression "to be of the opinion" is a bit weird, almost as if there is an implied word that is missing. I'm left wondering if there are languages where this genetive-type construction isn't allowed, and if native speakers of those languages won't find this explanation useful/convincing. I guess they'll just have to shrug and accept "this is just something Germanic languages do".

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Another thing English and German do is to use dative constructions with meanings very similar to this genitive one: "It seems to me" and "Es scheint mir".

Comment: Just for reference, Italian, despite not being a Germanic language, uses the exact same constructions ("I am of the opinion that..." and "it seems to me that..."). So it seems to me that it is more an Indo-European thing.

Comment: Which is it? "I am of the opinion" - the opinion is mine; "I am of the understanding" - the opinion, or fact, is someone else's. Or, is it not possible to distinguish form this German phrase?

Comment: Of course it depends on context but it doesn't really have a direct correspondent in English: [dict.cc | Auffassung](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Auffassung)

Comment: Auffassung *does not receive any action/object* – Do you maybe want to say that *sein* does not receive any object here?

Comment: No. Compare "Ich gebe es der Frau". In this case Frau would receive something and thus be in dative.

Answer (score 5):

Of course *ich bin der Auffassung* has a similar meaning as *I believe* or *I am convinced*, but makes a more eloquent impression (imagine e. g. a politician) without adding substance.

*I think* is much weaker in my opinion, since it could just reflect a spontaneous idea.

The degree of certainty is crucial here, and *der Auffassung sein* implies some consideration, but less than *der Überzeugung sein* (to be convinced).

Comment: This does not address the question which is about the grammatical construct behind this, not the meaning.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the top answer, "ich bin der Auffassung" also implicitly describes that a specific process has led the person to come to the stated conclusion, which can be described as his **understanding** of things. **'Auffassungsgabe'** is a related word which describes the ability of a person to notice and consider relevant and observable things and come to a conclusion that approximates true causality.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. I think the first part of your answer is aiming at something relevant, but it’s not easy to understand if you are not a native speaker. Can you please [edit] your answer to expand this?